# Statefulset unable to mount volume - NFS shared volume

Tags: kubernetes

After deleting the pod and re-apply its unable to mount the pod. The volume is a NFS share and has mounted to other pods as well. It is set as `ReadWriteMany` so it should mount to other this pod as well.

`Describe pod`:

```
Warning  FailedMount  2m4s  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[test-nfs-share1], unattached volumes=[default-token-zkjpx test-nfs-share1]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

`kubectl get pvc  --all-namespaces`:

```
test-web-services   test-nfs-share1-pvc   Bound     test-nfs-share1                  1Gi        RWX                           25h
```

Comment: Which CSI Driver are you using?

Comment: Don't think I'm using any CSI driver. Its in a GCP cluster and I used the stroageClass name to "" (empty).

Comment: how do I check which CSI driver I'm using?

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266

Comment: Its exactly like that but still doesn't auto mount

Comment: It seems `kubectl describe pvc` shows that the volume is mounted by the pod already. Is there way to unmount the pod from PVC?  It was mounted before the delete and but the new pod that got created isn't mounted

Comment: you resolved unmounting from pvc problem?